# JavaScript Google Maps Geolocation How can I get the Zipcode, City, State from this?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, geolocation

OK, I am taking from an example I found, but my brain is fried from the heat, and google api's always do something to me, anyway

```
function codeLatLng(lat, lng)
{
    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);
    geocoder.geocode({'latLng': latlng}, function(results, status)
    {
        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK)
        {
            //console.log(results)
            if(results[1])
            {
                //formatted address
                //alert(results[0].formatted_address)
                //find country name
                $('#geolocation_latlng').html(latlng);
                for(var i=0; i<results[0].address_components.length; i++)
                {
                    for(var b=0;b<results[0].address_components[i].types.length;b++)
                    {

                        //there are different types that might hold a city admin_area_lvl_1 usually does in come cases looking for sublocality type will be more appropriate
                        if(results[0].address_components[i].types[b] == "administrative_area_level_1")
                        {
                            //this is the object you are looking for
                            city=results[0].address_components[i];
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
            //city data
            //alert(city.short_name + " " + city.long_name)
            }
            else
            {
                alert("Could not Determin Location");
            }
      }
      else
      {
          alert("Location dection failed: " + status);
      }
    });
}
```

Its safe to assume the lat and lon are already being passed and I am getting a result, I commented out one alert for formated_address, What I am trying to do is figure out how I can take the zipcode, state, city from that formatted address and show it on screen. But like I said Im fried right now, and Im crunching a clock so I need a bit of help to kick start me.

Comment: Which countries are you working with?

Comment: Right now just the U.S. though leaving it open enough to expand upon in the future to other countries would be great, as I do intend on having other countries eventually visiting the site sooner or later

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[**My demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/yV6xv/132/) is comical collection of braces, but the idea is to look inside the [**results.types**](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geocoding#GeocodingAddressTypes) for:

```
 "locality"                     // CITY
 "administrative_area_level_1"  // STATE
 "postal_code"                  // ZIP
```

And as iterating, when you match these types, fill in the values. I asked for the country because this approach is explained in the docs to correspond to the US, but I have no idea, say if it's valid in Singapore. As they say, it's not an exact science.

So if you expand, you might have to check for country first, and match to another `wantedTypes` object with different correspondences to Google Maps' types (in another country the state might be Admin. area level 2).

I use the short name because most likely you want AZ and not Arizona. I didn't go as far to check if cities differ, e.g. St. Paul (short) vs. Saint Paul.

```
    if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
        if (results[0]) {
            var typeCorrespondence = {
                "city": "locality",
                "state": "administrative_area_level_1",
                "zipcode": "postal_code"
            };

            var geocoderResults = {};

            var components = results[0].address_components;

            for (var i = 0; i < components.length; i++) {
                for (var j = 0; j < components[i].types.length; j++) {

                    for (myType in typeCorrespondence) {
                        if (typeCorrespondence[myType] == components[i].types[j]) {
                            geocoderResults[myType] = components[i].short_name;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            $("#result").val(JSON.stringify(geocoderResults));
        }
    }
```

Comment: see, that makes a little more sense on it for me, is there a "dummies" version of the doc's somewhere where I can start out low and work up with this, cause my biggest issue was understanding the object that gets returned. ANyway thank you, this will help me much, in your advice should I attempt to work this logic into my original post or should I just go with what you have here as my new starting point?

Comment: Please see this update code here http://jsfiddle.net/yV6xv/134/ It is longer but cleaner and easier to understand. The final resulting object has "city, state, zip" properties :) (I'm going to update the answer in a second). My answer and your post have about the same structure, the differences begin in the `if(results[1])` block. I use `results[0]` but it should not matter as the geocoder usually returns 7 or 8 in that array. Since you have error notices and I don't, you should copy what I have inside that `if(results[0])` block. I think the docs are well-written, internals are hard to grasp.